# Determine if the sequence functions $f_n(x)=\frac{\sin(nx)+\cos(nx)}{\ln(n)}$ uniformly converges by Cauchy's criterion in $x\in[e,\infty)$

Tags: calculus

Determine if the sequence functions $f_n(x)=\frac{\sin(nx)+\cos(nx)}{\ln(n)}$ uniformly converges by Cauchy's criterion in $x\in[e,\infty)$

***Attempt:***

Let $0<\varepsilon $ we chose $\displaystyle n^{*} =\left\lceil \frac{1}{\varepsilon }\right\rceil +1$

Therefore, for all $n^*<n,k$ and for all $x\in[e,\infty)$ exists

\begin{aligned}
\Bigl|\frac{\sin( nx) +\cos( nx)}{\ln( n)} -\frac{\sin( kx) +\cos( kx)}{\ln( k)}\Bigl| & \leq \Bigl|\frac{\sin( nx) +\cos( nx)}{\ln( n)}\Bigl|\\
 & \leq \Bigl|\frac{\sin^{2}( nx) +\cos^{2}( nx)}{\ln( n)}\Bigl|\\
 & \leq \Bigl|\frac{1}{\ln( n)}\Bigl|\\
 &  < \varepsilon 
\end{aligned}

I noticed I have a few mistakes with my attempt and I'm unable to think of another direction to solve this question by Cauchy's Criterion.
Would appreciate some help with this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $|\sin u+\cos u|\le \sqrt{2}$, you can simply write
$$
\left|\frac{\sin( nx) +\cos( nx)}{\ln( n)} -\frac{\sin( kx) +\cos( kx)}{\ln( k)}\right|
{\le
\left|\frac{\sin( nx) +\cos( nx)}{\ln( n)}\right| +\left|\frac{\sin( kx) +\cos( kx)}{\ln( k)}\right|
\\\le
\frac{\sqrt 2}{\ln n}+\frac{\sqrt 2}{\ln k}
\\
<\epsilon,
}
$$
where the last inequality takes place for example when $n,k> \exp(\frac{3}{\epsilon})$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If you can please elaborate on the last inequality I don't see how if $\displaystyle n,k >e^{\frac{3}{\varepsilon }}$ solves the question. By plugging that into the inequality I get:  $\displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\frac{3}{\varepsilon }} +\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\frac{3}{\varepsilon }} =\frac{\sqrt{2} \cdotp \varepsilon }{3} +\frac{\sqrt{2} \cdotp \varepsilon }{3}$. Additionally I'm not sure this inequality holds for $\displaystyle n,k >e^{\frac{3}{\varepsilon }}$. I think it to should be the exact opposite - $\displaystyle n,k <e^{\frac{3}{\varepsilon }}$.

Comment: You're welcome. Sure I will elaborate. Generally in using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limits, you need not use strict bounds. Rather, sufficient conditions can help much. For example in this case, I have assumed that the conditions $\frac{\sqrt 2}{\ln n}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $\frac{\sqrt 2}{\ln k}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ are sufficient for deduction of $\frac{\sqrt 2}{\ln n}+\frac{\sqrt 2}{\ln k}<\epsilon$, both of which yielding $n,k>\exp(\frac{2\sqrt 2}{\epsilon})$. The final answer uses only a better notation since $3>2\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: You're welcome. Sure I will elaborate. Generally in using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limits, you need not use strict bounds. Rather, sufficient conditions can help much. For example in this case, I have assumed that the conditions $\frac{\sqrt 2}{\ln n}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $\frac{\sqrt 2}{\ln k}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ are sufficient for deduction of $\frac{\sqrt 2}{\ln n}+\frac{\sqrt 2}{\ln k}<\epsilon$, both of which yielding $n,k>\exp(\frac{2\sqrt 2}{\epsilon})$. The final answer uses only a better notation since $3>2\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: There is actually nothing special about $3$ as long as it is more than $2\sqrt 2$.

Answer (score 2):

$|f_n(x)|=|\frac{\sin(nx)+\cos(nx)}{\ln(n)}|
=
\sqrt{2} |\frac{ \sin(nx +\pi/4)}{\ln(n)}| \leq \sqrt{2} \frac{1}{\ln(n)}.$ The right side converges to $0,$ and this whole process is indepent of of the choice of $x.$

Edit: If you want to use the Cauchy criterion, the proof is essentially the same. Do this same business for both fractions. Without loss of generality, we can choose one guy that is bigger than another one: say, $ k>n.$ Then we've $$ |f_n(x) -f_k(x)|\leq \frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{\ln(n)}.$$ This shows that $f_n$ is Cauchy.

Extra: Note that $a \sin(x) +b \cos(x) \leq \sqrt{a^2 +b^2.}$

Comment: The OP asks for proof by Cauchy's criteria.

Comment: My bad. But it's pretty much the same proof.

Comment: Yes, just do this for both numerators in the question, then it follows.

Comment: I fixed the errors. Thanks so much.